# No qualifying bean of type AbstractRepository<?>' available: expected single matching bean but found 2

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using spring-boot to implement some rest-endpoint. I have implements an AbstractRepository and an AbstractEnpoint with is @Autowired. Both are then extended by the really 2 Endpoints: ClientEndpoint and HospitalReservationListEndpoint. 
But I get the following error in the Browser when I try to call methods in Endpoints that neccessite the repository:

`"org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.parcaune.reservationmanagerservices.core.AbstractRepository<?>' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: clientRepository,hospitalReservationListRepository"`

My Classes:

My AbstractRepository

```
/*
@NoRepositoryBean
Annotation to exclude repository interfaces from being picked up
and thus in consequence getting an instance being created
*/

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface AbstractRepository<T> extends JpaRepository<T, String> 
{
}
```

My AbstractEndpoint

```
public abstract class AbstractEndpoint<T> {

  @Autowired
  protected AbstractRepository<T> repository;

  @GET
  @Path("/ping")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String ping() {
    return "Endpoint works!";
  }

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public List<T> getAll() {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list = repository.findAll();
    return list;
  }
}
```

My Client-Classes:

```
public interface ClientRepository extends AbstractRepository<Client> {
}
```

and

```
@Component
@Path("/clients")
public class ClientEndpoint extends AbstractEndpoint<Client> {
}
```

My Hospital-Classes

```
public interface HospitalReservationListRepository extends 
AbstractRepository<HospitalReservationList> {
}
```

and

```
@Component
@Path("/hospitalreservationlist")
public class HospitalReservationListEndpoint extends 
AbstractEndpoint<HospitalReservationList> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to add Repository as a Generic parameter like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractEndpoint<T,R extends AbstractRepository<T>> {

  @Autowired
  protected R repository;

...
```

I hope there is a better way to do this, if you can find one please comment it here.

Comment: I get the same error after change the code like you

Comment: I remember a case when we got that error when we try to run the application with Eclipse, however when we run it with mvn spring-boot:run we didn't have any problems. Try to run it with mvn spring-boot:run maybe it  will help to find the problem.

Comment: I get the same Error again

Comment: Another idea, I'm not sure it matters, but I allways use @Autowired contructor or setter. Have you tried it that way?